# My javascript is in jquery/eval/seq/ folder and can not be changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Strangely, I stuck with the following code using jquery 2.0.0:

```
$.when(
 $.getJSON('get_one.php', function(data) { code_1 },
 $.getJSON('get_two.php', function(data) { code_2 }
 ).done(function() {

   //ready_program_block 
   $.getJSON('get_three', function(data) { code_3 });

 }
```

So, this worked well (or at least I think so), until the moment when I decided to change ready_program_block. Now the old ready_program_block is executed (with errors as expected and properly reported in the FireBug).

Looking into the script section of the same FireBug, I see that my javascript is coming from **my_site.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js/eval/seq/** where it is named as '2', and not from **my_site.com/my_script.js** where it should be.

So, what is jquery/eval/seq/ and why I can not change my code?
Still, I did not rename my_script.js, eventually that will break connection with eval/seq/ I think, but first I want to resolve that strange issue.

Regarding the script: I want ready_program_block (respectively $.getJSON('get_three', ...) to be executed only after all data from the first 2 getJSON-s is properly received from the browser and not before that, may be there is a better way of doing that.

Comment: Shouldn't it be get_three.php? That's said, if one of your request is rejected, $.when() callaback is fired instantly (get_one.php or get_two.php), so not waiting for any other deferred to be resolved. Have you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Cache cleared 'Firefox/Clear cache/All' but to no avail. I think that the whole mystery is connected with the deferred jquery functions, but how to clear jquery cache if that is a cache at all?

Comment: Renaming script file solved the issue, so I can update code inside the done function as usual, but the whole thing seems very strange, like a bug in jquery.  Btw, updating jquery to 2.0.2 didn't help, same old code broke inside done function.

Comment: I have the same issue and trying to find a fix for this.. it is very strange indeed..